# Show Woocommerce cart subtotal crossed out regular price with sale price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Having a problem getting the Woocommerce cart subtotal price to show a crossed-out regular price and a sale price.

I have tried working with

```
<?php
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
?>
```

However, I've had no luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
                            if($cart_item[ 'data' ]->is_on_sale()){

                            echo '<del aria-hidden="true"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().'</span>'.$cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_regular_price() * $cart_item['quantity'].'</bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().'</span>'.$cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_price() * $cart_item['quantity'].'</bdi></span></ins>'; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        }else{
                            
                            echo '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().'</span>'.$cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_price() * $cart_item['quantity'].'</bdi></span>'; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        }
                        ?>
```